# Bind arguments in different order

Tags: javascript, arguments, currying

Say I have

```
function bake(egg, milk, batter) { ... }
```

And I already have the egg. Then I might do this

```
var f = bake.bind(null, theEgg);
```

to create a function that does the rest of the work.

But: what if I have the milk or the batter and I want to bind it, and it's the *first* argument that will be passed in later? Is there a functional way to twist the arguments **without just creating an anonymous intermediary function and manually twisting the arguments** so I can have fluid, functional-looking code with the argument bound?

Comment: In functional languages, functions are typically curried, so you can't immediately access the arguments out of order anyway. That's why Haskell has functionals like `flip`. I'd write out some signatures, but it kind of bothers me that you have "batter" as an argument, when usually "egg" and "milk" go into the batter so I'd rather not .

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for partial application, with placeholder. Here's a helper:

```
var _ = {} // placeholder

var partial = function(f) {
  var as = [].slice.call(arguments, 1)
  return function() {
    var args = as.concat([].slice.call(arguments))
    for (var i=args.length; i--;)
      if (args[i] === _)
        args[i] = args.splice(-1)[0]
    return f.apply(null, args)
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
partial(bake, _, theMilk, _)(theEgg, theBatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an object is usually the way to do this

```
var ingredients = {
    egg: theEgg,
    milk: theMilk,
    batter: theBatter
}

bake(ingredients);
```

Then you can vary the order in which egg, milk or batter are added to `ingredients` and you can handle `null` or `undefined` values within your `bake` method.

There are also libraries (e.g. jQuery `extend`) that allow you to merge 2 objects together, so for example, you could have a default set of ingredients that are `extended` with the values provided in the arguments